# Compare and swap value in atomic integer kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, atomicinteger

Hey I am learning atomic integer in kotlin. I want to know is there atomic integer swap value if current value is smaller than new value. For example

AtomicInt 10

**Scenario 1** new value is **5** and it changes to 5 because 5 is lower than 10

**Scenario 2** new value is **20** it will not change the atomic value because 20 is greater than 10.

Can we do this throught [CompareAndSwap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native.concurrent/-atomic-int/compare-and-swap.html#compareandswap) function?

UPDATE after [@LouisWasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) suggestion

```
fun AtomicInt.compareAndSetIfLess(newValue: Int): Boolean {
    do {
        val oldValue = value
        if (newValue > oldValue) {
            return false
        }
    } while (!compareAndSet(oldValue, newValue))
    return true
}
```

I am getting error on `Unresolved reference: AtomicInt`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The following is a compareAndSet version, which I think is what you want, but it's easy enough to change it to compareAndSet:

```
fun AtomicInt.compareAndSetIfLess(newValue: Int): Boolean {
  do {
    val oldValue = value
    if (newValue > oldValue) {
      return false
    }
  } while (!compareAndSet(oldValue, newValue))
  return true
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply me. I want to know what is d/w [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and [AtomicInt](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native.concurrent/-atomic-int/)?

Comment: There's no real difference, they're just separately built for different platforms.  Use https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.atomicfu so you don't have to worry.

Comment: I am trying to add the dependency but it giving error in my gradle file. Can you tell me which one I need to add in my gradle function?

Comment: No, I can't.  I don't use Gradle.

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman. I downloaded from main source. Thanks a million ☺️